# setlocale cache date php

Tags: php, date, time, setlocale

I would like to ask for your help to enable the correct language to the following parameter .data

```
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ita', 'it_IT', 'it_IT.UTF-8');
echo '<!-- cached page - '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', filemtime($cache_file)).', Page : '.$dynamic_url.' -->';
```

I would like to translate the .date in it_IT but the output result is in en_EN. Where is the error?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use .date as it is not locale-aware.

> **FROM PHP MANUAL**
>
> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and
> strftime() functions instead of date().

So the easy answer is to use [strftime()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function instead of date()